# Is there a way to extract items from list returned from a function, then use those items within the next function?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a RPN calculator which takes in

```
3
3
*
4
4
*
+
=
```

and returns the result once `=` is entered. I have so far managed to get it to work for individual expressions ie

```
3
3
*
=
```

and

```
4
4
*
=
```

but I am struggling to get it to go further than storing the result from the first expression and calculating the second, let alone combining both results to get the final result.

I've changed it about a lot, but the current version I have is like this:

```
def user_inputs():
    print("in inputs func:")
    operators = {'+', '-', '*', '/', '%', '='}
    inputs = [0]
    print("initial inputs: ", inputs)  

while True:
        blank = input()
        if blank == '=':
            inputs.append(blank)
            return inputs
        elif blank not in operators: #if integer
            inputs.append(int(blank))
            print("inputs: ", inputs)
        elif blank in operators: #if operator
            inputs.append(blank)
            print("op inputs: ", inputs)

            checking = inputs[-3:]
            print("checking: ", checking)
            if type(checking[0]) is int and type(checking[1]) is int and checking[2] in operators:
                return inputs
        else:
            print("Unrecognised operator or operand ", blank)
            continue


def calculation(inputs):
    inputs = inputs()
    stack = []

    for a in inputs:
        stack.append(a)
        continue

    checking = stack[-3:]
    operators = {'+', '-', '*', '/', '%', '='}
    if type(checking[0]) is int and type(checking[1]) is int and checking[2] in operators:
        stack.pop()


    op2, op1 = stack[-1], stack[-2]
    print("op1 and op2: ", op1, op2)

    if '+' in inputs:    #code for addition
        result = op1 + op2
        stack.append(result)
                                         #user_inputs() position 1


    elif '-' in inputs: #code for subtraction
        result = op1 - op2
        stack.append(result)

    elif '/' in inputs: #code for division
        if op2 == 0: #if division by 0 is attempted
            print("Divide by 0.")
            exit()#see how to leave the function so that it doesnt crash
        else:
            result = int(op1 / op2)
            stack.append(result)

    elif '*' in inputs: #code for multiplication
        result = op1 * op2
        stack.append(result)

    elif '%' in inputs:
        if op2 == 0:
            print("Divide by 0.")
            exit()
        else:
            result = op1 % op2
            stack.append(result)


    if stack[-1] >= 2147483647:  # if above limit
        return 2147483647
    elif stack[-1] <= -2147483648: # if below limit
        return -2147483648
    else:
        return stack[-1]
                                                    #user_inputs() position 2


while True: 
    print("\nRESULT:", calculation(user_inputs), "\n")
```

I have searched for ways to do this but haven't found anything I understand to use. I was thinking of calling `user_input()` within `calculation()`, but then I do not know where would be suitable to place it. When I tried calling it in position 1, it let me input the second part of the expression but wouldn't go back and do the calculation. Maybe it's because of where I placed it? But I still am not even sure this approach is correct/could ever do what I want it to.
Is there a way to get the inputs again and somehow return to `calculation()` at a point where it would be possible to do any of the mathematical operators?

Comment: For one thing, you look at the top of the stack to determine if there is an operator there, and then you throw it away.  You need to use *that* operator  to know what to do with op1 and op2.  Rescanning the input won't help you, since you may get somewhere else's operator.

Comment: For RPN, the operator never needs to go on the stack. Numerical inputs go on the stack; an operator input is a signal to *remove* an appropriate number of items from the stack, apply the operator you just read to them, then put the result on the stack. The `=` is just a signal to stop reading input and to report the top of the stack as the final result.

Comment: @chepner, now the issue is that the way the code is structured, it needs to go from inputs to calc back to inputs.

Comment: I tried from_calc.append(add()) where add is a fucntion that adds and from_calc is where the results will be stored, but it is not working